# Magento Google checkout restrict free shipping for Hawaii and alaska

Tags: magento, google-checkout

how do i restrict free shipping for Hawaii and alaska from Magento google checkout Merchant calculated shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article from google about how to restrict areas using their API.

[Google Checkout XML API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculated_Shipping.html)

I also use the free version of this module to segment Alaska/Hawaii, but the paid version apparently supports google checkout:

[WebShopApps Premium Matrixrate - $80](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-premium-matrixrate-multiple-tablerate-shipping.html)